# Cumsum with plyr ddply is not keeping running total

Tags: r, plyr, cumsum

I'm trying to use `cumsum`, with `plyr`'s `ddply` to have a running total. However, I just don't understand why this does not work.

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 

dd = data.frame(n, s)
#   n  s
# 1 2 aa
# 2 3 bb
# 3 5 cc

test <-ddply(dd, "n", transform, ttl = cumsum(n))
#   n  s ttl
# 1 2 aa   2
# 2 3 bb   3
# 3 5 cc   5
```

What I expect `ttl` should be is:

```
#  2
#  5
# 10
```

It'd be great if anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong here and how I can obtain the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: The output is as expected, since you are grouping based on the variable `n`. `cumsum` is being computed for each subset of `dd` based on `n`. To get the output you seek, just do `dd$ttl <- cumsum(dd$n)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the result is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, ddply works completly fine.

However I think you want ttl be the cumulative sum of n. So use this (also simpler) code:

```
dd$ttl <- cumsum(dd$n)
```